# awesome_print not showing associated objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, printing, awesomeprint

How do I get AwesomePrint.ap to show the associated objects that are nested inside an object? It doesn't do this by default and I'm assuming there's a way to force it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `raw` parameter, e.g.

```
ap my_model, raw: true
```

This recursively formats instance variables. You can also make it the default using `AwesomePrint.defaults` ([Documentation](https://github.com/michaeldv/awesome_print#setting-custom-defaults))

But beware: That feature can add a large amount of noise, especially when printing Rails related object instances. (especially `ActiveRecord::Base`)

Comment: sorry for the long response/acceptance. thanks a ton for this. Just what I was looking for.